# C++ read()-ing from a socket to an ofstream

Tags: c++, c, sockets

Is there a C/C++ way to read data from a socket using read() and having the receiving buffer be a file (ofstream) or a similar self-extending object (vector e.g.)?

**EDIT:**  The question arose while I contemplated how to read a stream socket that may receive the contents of a, say 10000+ byte file.  I just never did like putting 20000 or 50000 bytes (large enough for now) on the stack as a buffer where the file could be stored temporarily till I could stick in into a file.  Why not just stream it directly into the file to star with.

Much like you can get at the char* inside a std:string, I thought of something like

```
read( int fd, outFile.front(), std::npos );  // npos = INT_MAX
```

or something like that.

**end edit**

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Quite a few people have written stream buffers that connect to sockets. While they initially seem cool, at least from what I've seen, they rarely work all that well in practice. You (nearly) need to add some sort of asynchronous operation (e.g., like ASIO does) to get it to work well. http://socketstream.sourceforge.net/, http://www.pcs.cnu.edu/~dgame/sockets/socketsC++/sockets.html, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simplistic, and off the top of my fingers, but I think something along these lines would work out:

```
template <unsigned BUF_SIZE>
struct Buffer {
    char buf_[BUF_SIZE];
    int len_;
    Buffer () : buf_(), len_(0) {}
    int read (int fd) {
        int r = read(fd, buf_ + len_, BUF_SIZE - len_);
        if (r > 0) len_ += r;
        return r;
    }
    int capacity () const { return BUF_SIZE - len_; }
}

template <unsigned BUF_SIZE>
struct BufferStream {
    typedef std::unique_ptr< Buffer<BUF_SIZE> > BufferPtr;
    std::vector<BufferPtr> stream_;
    BufferStream () : stream_(1, BufferPtr(new Buffer<BUF_SIZE>)) {}
    int read (int fd) {
        if ((*stream_.rbegin())->capacity() == 0)
            stream_.push_back(BufferPtr(new Buffer<BUF_SIZE>));
        return (*stream_.rbegin())->read(fd);
    }
};
```

In a comment, you mentioned you wanted to avoid creating a big char buffer. When using the `read` system call, it is generally more efficient to perform a few large reads rather than many small ones. So most implementations will opt for large input buffers to gain that efficiency. You could implement something like:

```
std::vector<char> input;
char in;
int r;
while ((r = read(fd, &in, 1)) == 1) input.push_back(in);
```

But that would involve a system call and at least one byte copied for every byte of input. In contrast, the code I put forth avoids extra data copies.

I don't really expect the code I put out to be the solution you would adopt. I just wanted to provide you with an illustration of how to create a self-extending object that was fairly space and time efficient. Depending on your purposes, you may want to extend it, or write your own. Off the top of my head, some improvements may be:

- use `std::list` instead, to avoid vector resizing
- allow API a parameter to specify how many bytes to read
- use `readv` to always allow at least `BUF_SIZE` bytes (or more than `BUF_SIZE` bytes) to be read at a time

Comment: Interesting.  What I really was after was a way not to have to declare a big char buffer.  But in struct Buffer {    char buf_[BUF_SIZE];... you are declaring a char buffer.

Comment: @WesMiller: `read` needs to be passed a buffer, and you wanted the data collected in a self-extending data structure, which means storing the buffers after `read` returns. If you really want no buffers created in user space code, you are looking at creating your own network I/O device driver with 0 copy semantics (direct access to network buffers used by the kernel).

Comment: OK, not going that far.  I contemplated the self-extending object for cases in which the received data stream (it's a stream socket) was of unknown size.  As edited in the original posting above, I will be receiving a file of unknown size and hoped not to have to hope char buffer[50000] was "large enough".  Guaranteed not to be sooner or later.

Comment: @WesMiller: `BUF_SIZE` is a template parameter to allow tweaking to the buffer size. Generally, it should be a size that matches the expected data rate of the input multiplied by the interval of time between read calls.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at stream support in [**`boost::asio`**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/streambuf.html).